# Reading vertexes and indices from a Spatial​Surface​Mesh​Buffer

Tags: c#, uwp, directx, sharpdx, hololens

I'm developing a HoloLens UWP app using SharpDX (a C# DirectX wrapper), and I want to process the spatial mapping data generated by the device.

I have managed to get a list of [Spatial​Surface​Mesh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Perception.Spatial.Surfaces.SpatialSurfaceMesh), which contain the meshes describing the environment, and they have two properties -TriangleIndices and VertexPositions- that I am interested in reading.

The issue is that they are instances of [Spatial​Surface​Mesh​Buffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Perception.Spatial.Surfaces.SpatialSurfaceMeshBuffer#Windows_Perception_Spatial_Surfaces_SpatialSurfaceMeshBuffer_ElementCount), which contain an IBuffer with the raw data, alongside with the ElementCount, Stride(length of each element) an 
DirectXPixelFormat, and while that format is optimal for rendering the mesh using DirectX I don't know how to read the coordinates of the vertexes and the order of the indices to use them in my app.

I guess I have to somehow read the data from the IBuffer using the specified Stride and Format, but I haven't been able to find any documentation about how to do it, any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://forums.hololens.com/discussion/2070/world-coordinates-from-meshes-vertexpositions-data) link IBuffer is just a wrapper around byte[] and the vectors are (most of the time) saved in that order x,y,z,w. The format (if int16, float or whatever is used) can be found out by looking into the [`Format`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.directx.directxpixelformat) property of the [`Spatial​Surface​Mesh​Buffer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Perception.Spatial.Surfaces.SpatialSurfaceMeshBuffer#Windows_Perception_Spatial_Surfaces_SpatialSurfaceMeshBuffer_ElementCount) class. This property also defines if the values are stored in a different order or if additional transformations are neccesary to get the correct position.

So basicly you could do something like

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;

Spatial​Surface​Mesh​Buffer surfaceMeshBuffer = ...
byte[] data = surfaceMeshBuffer.ToArray();
var vectors = new List<Vector4>();    

for(int i = 0; i < data.length; ) {
    float x  = System.BitConverter.ToSingle(data, i);
    i += sizeof(float) / 8;
    float y  = System.BitConverter.ToSingle(data, i);        
    i += sizeof(float) / 8;
    float z  = System.BitConverter.ToSingle(data, i);        
    i += sizeof(float) / 8;
    float w  = System.BitConverter.ToSingle(data, i);        
    i += sizeof(float) / 8; 

    vectors.Add(new Vector4(x, y, z, w));
}
```